# Bitwise Complement

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

I have a sample problem with `w=1`, `y=7`, `z=0`, `x = ~(w && y) | y;` and the solution is `x = -1`, but I can't figure out why?

Here is my thought process:
(w && y) = (1 && 7) = 1
~1
1 in bits is `0000 0001`
~1 in bits is `1111 1110`

Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: What's `1111 1110` ored with `111`?

Comment: So far so good.  Now you have `(1111 1110) | y`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last step is a bitwise OR so you get:

```
1111 1110 | 0000 0111 = 1111 1111
```

which is -1.

Answer (score 1):

~1 in bits is `1111 1110`,
`1111 1110` or `0000 0111` is `1111 1111`,
and `1111 1111` is -1. The most significant bit is the negative flag, and negative numbers are subtractive, I guess you could say. That's why a signed byte can hold down to -128 but only up to 127.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that `~(w && y)` gives `1111...0`. The last bit of `7` is `1`, so `|`ing this with 7 gives `1111...1`, or `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using `&` instead of `&&` for bitwise operations.  Second, after `~1 = 111...1110` is calculated, it is ORed with `y` (7) to get `1111..1111`, the 2's-complement representation of -1.

Comment: I would not suggest that, as you do not know the intention of the code (at least I don't know what it really does) and the results of & and && are different.